# Heroku Eco Dynos Plan

Tags: heroku

I have three apps on heroku and currently they are unavailable maybe due to the newest update of paid plans in heroku. Now i want to pay. Do I have to pay for the three apps individually or one payment will cover the three apps.

I tried making payments but a bit confused so I need help in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

If you subscribed to Eco dynos, one payment 5$ per month will cover them all. But it does not include databases if you have on Heroku. There you have to pay separately.

Comment: "one payment 5$ per month will cover them all"—well, to a point. This gives you 1000 dyno hours per month. "I have converted my apps to eco version, and what I have noticed the API apps seems not able to process requests anymore…"—please don't ask questions as part of your answer. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum, and questions should be firmly separated from answers.